# Matlab returning text on a push button

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am just starting to learn about push buttons and i am stuck.  I have two pop up menus.  When the user selects the push button.  the total from each pop up menu selection is returned to the user.  I got the values from the pop up menu but I dont know how to return it after the push button is executed.  Any help is appreciated

```
 function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

 math=0;

 data1 =get(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value')  %processing data from first pop up menu
 if data1== 1
 math=1
 elseif data1 == 2
    math=4
 end
 data2=get(handles.popupmenu2, 'Value')  %processing data from second pop up menu
 if data2==1
    math=math + 5;
 end
 % I tabulated math which is some number.  I want to return it back to the user 
 in  a text outside of the button.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way then returning the value: You pass and store it within the guidata-structure. Search for guidata in the docs for detailed information. One example from the docs:

```
function My_Callback()
% ...
% Get the structure using guidata in the local function
myhandles = guidata(gcbo);
% Modify the value of your counter
myhandles.numberOfErrors = myhandles.numberOfErrors + 1;
% Save the change you made to the structure
guidata(gcbo,myhandles)
```

Short explanation how to do it:

**1.** get the data by myhandles=guidata(handle_of_the_figure)

**2.** add/modify data, like myhandles.Test = 123

**3.** dont forget to save the changes, otherwise they will "just disappear"-> use guidata(handle_of_the_figure,myhandles)

**4.** to test it, just load the guidata afterwards within another function and look for the changes!

**EDIT**

while re-reading your question, it came to my mind, that you perhaps just want a value calculated within your callback to be displayed somewhere else. for example, if you want the value showing up in an text-edit uicontrol, you can use:

```
set(HandleOfTheTextEdit, 'String', num2str(mat))
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elaborate, but more powerful way would be to create your own handle class.

Doing that you could add callbacks to custom data. I did an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153044/is-it-possible-to-do-stateless-programming-in-matlab-how-to-avoid-checking-d/9153153#9153153).

Comment: +1 for showing something I didnt know befor. this is some next-level Matlab-programming :) will try next time, seems to be useful for larger sets of data(?)